# keras flow_from_dataframe semantic segmentation

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to use keras' flow_from_dataframe for semantic segmentation (input is an image of dimension (height, width, 3), label is also an image of dimension (height, width), but can't get it to work.

As recommended [here](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-flow-from-dataframe-1fd4493d237c) I (uninstalled the existing and) installed the latest keras preprocessing lib with

```
    pip install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing.git
```

I'm getting following error for below mini example

**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)**

Using following versions in an anaconda virtual environment on Windows 7 in Pycharm

- tf 1.13.1
- keras-preprocessing 1.0.9
- keras 2.2.4
- keras-applications 1.0.7
- keras-base 2.2.4

I think the error lies in my usage of flow_from_dataframe, as I was able to write my own keras datagenerator following this [blog](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).

Any advice, how to correctly setup flow_from_dataframe?

Fully working example which also generates the random training data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import scipy.misc

import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


def get_file_list(root_path):
    """
    # Returns:
        file_list: _list_, list of full paths to all files found
    """
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
        for name in files:
            file_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return file_list


def gen_rand_img_labels(n_rand_imgs, path_img, path_label):
    for i in range(n_rand_imgs):
        img_rand = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=img_dim)
        scipy.misc.toimage(img_rand, cmin=0, cmax=255).save(os.path.join(path_img, 'img{}.png'.format(i)))

        label_rand = np.random.randint(0, n_classes, size=(img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))
        print('label_rand.shape: ', label_rand.shape)
        scipy.misc.toimage(label_rand, cmin=0, cmax=255).save(os.path.join(path_label, 'img{}.png'.format(i)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    img_dim = (100, 200, 3)  # height, width, channels
    batch_size = 1
    nr_epochs = 1

    n_classes = 5
    n_rand_imgs = 10
    savepath_img = r'/path/to/img'
    savepath_label = r'/path/to/label'

    # --- generate random images and random labels and save them to disk
    gen_rand_img_labels(n_rand_imgs, savepath_img, savepath_label)


    # --- build Data Generator
    train_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['path', 'label'])

    list_img_names = get_file_list(savepath_img)

    for fname in list_img_names:
        fname_pure = os.path.split(fname)[1]

        # read in png label file as numpy array
        y = scipy.misc.imread(os.path.join(savepath_label, fname_pure))
        y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y, n_classes)
        print('shape y: {}'.format(y.shape))
        train_df.loc[len(train_df)] = [fname, y]

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.0, validation_split=0.25)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col="path",
        y_col="label",
        subset="training",
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="raw",
        target_size=(img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))


    valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col="path",
        y_col="label",
        subset="validation",
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="raw",
        target_size=(img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))

    # --- create the model and train it
    input_ = Input(shape=img_dim)
    x = Conv2D(n_classes, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1')(input_)
    model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[x])
    model.summary()

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

    # Train model
    STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size
    STEP_SIZE_VALID = valid_generator.n // valid_generator.batch_size
    model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                        validation_data=valid_generator,
                        validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                        epochs=nr_epochs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code for use with TensorFlow 2.0

NOTE: Use scipy 1.2.0, as `scipy.misc.toimage` is deprecated in later versions.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import scipy.misc

def get_file_list(root_path):
    """
    # Returns:
        file_list: _list_, list of full paths to all files found
    """
    file_list = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
        for name in files:
            file_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return file_list

def gen_rand_img_labels(n_rand_imgs, path_img, path_label):
    for i in range(n_rand_imgs):
        img_rand = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=img_dim)
        PIL.Image.fromarray(img_rand, cmin=0, cmax=255).save(os.path.join(path_img, 'img{}.png'.format(i)))

        label_rand = np.random.randint(0, n_classes, size=(img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))
        print('label_rand.shape: ', label_rand.shape)
        PIL.Image.fromarray(label_rand, cmin=0, cmax=255).save(os.path.join(path_label, 'img{}.png'.format(i)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img_dim = (100, 200, 3)  # height, width, channels
    batch_size = 1
    nr_epochs = 1

    n_classes = 5
    n_rand_imgs = 10
    savepath_img = r''
    savepath_label = r''

    # --- generate random images and random labels and save them to disk
    gen_rand_img_labels(n_rand_imgs, savepath_img, savepath_label)


    # --- build Data Generator
    train_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['path', 'label'])

    list_img_names = get_file_list(savepath_img)

    for fname in list_img_names:
        fname_pure = os.path.split(fname)[1]

        # read in png label file as numpy array
        y = scipy.misc.imread(os.path.join(savepath_label, fname_pure))
        y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, n_classes)
        print('shape y: {}'.format(y.shape))
        train_df.loc[len(train_df)] = [fname, y]

    datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.0, validation_split=0.25)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col="path",
        y_col="label",
        subset="training",
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="raw",
        target_size=(img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))


    valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        x_col="path",
        y_col="label",
        subset="validation",
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="raw",
        target_size=(img_dim[0], img_dim[1]))

    # --- create the model and train it
    input_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=img_dim)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_classes, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1')(input_)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[x])
    model.summary()

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

    # Train model
    STEP_SIZE_TRAIN = train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size
    STEP_SIZE_VALID = valid_generator.n // valid_generator.batch_size
    model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                        validation_data=valid_generator,
                        validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                        epochs=nr_epochs)
```